# Here's one for you

Tags: riddle

> I was alive in the beginning, I'm still alive today.
>   I live in the ocean, but I'm also found in space.
>   I'm one and yet many, singular like the many islands in the ocean.
>   Simple in structure and yet I can be found on the international space station.
>   I can live under water or in the vast reaches of space. 
>   Oh and if you want to visit me I'll be at the --um b--ke-

Answer (score 11):

You are:

> Plankton!
>  They are can be single celled organisms. But are used in the ISS to generate oxygen through photosynthesis. Finally shout out to spongebob square pants he will be at the Chum Bucket, Plankton's establishment in Spongebob.